# Testing the first digit of an integer

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm working with some code that I don't have access to to change. This code returns a single integer, the first digit of which denotes the privilege status of the current user. For example, an elevated user with an ID of 1234 would return the userID of 11234. The same user at a non-elevated level would return 01234. Whilst this concatenates the user reference neatly, I need to store the boolean value of the users elevation separately.

I could take the first character by converting the integer to a string value - however, converting from an integer to a string, performing the operation, converting to an integer and subsequently a boolean seems unnecessary. How can I simplify this process?

```
bool isElevated = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32((resultID.ToString()).Substring(0, 1)));
```

Comment: If the first digit returned [of a non-zero value] is a 0, it's already not an integer.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I've realised now that there must be some difference between the documentation and the return type. Printing the result to console where there is a preceding zero outputs the preceding zero, so it definitely isn't being clipped. However, it also isn't an integer if it precedes with a zero. Could it be a long?

Comment: Does intellisense not reveal the type? I'm having a hard time imagining it's not a string if there's a leading zero, the value is not zero, and it's not a decimal with a value -1 < x < 1.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I think I have an answer. The datatype is actually a short, and the length of the short is tested before being released. If it has a... *shorter* length than 5 digits, it is padded with underscores, which the console is printing as zeroes. 

I think I'm going to simply convert the userID to a string as soon as possible and write separate methods for conversions to boolean values instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first digit of an integer cannot be zero!  The only exception to this is when the integer *is* `0`.

You need to be careful about how the information is stored.  If you're receiving an `int` from someone elses auto-magic code, then you have to understand that when there is a zero in front of the `int` it's going to to be clipped off because it's unimportant to a numerical value. 01 is still 1 according to the computer.

Sample code demonstrating this problem:

```
//Their process should add zero to beginning
bool isUserElevated = false;
//The ID before auto-magic
string yourInitialID = "1234";
//Other person's process of adding identifier
if (isUserElevated == true)
{
    yourInitialID = "1" + yourInitialID;
}
else
{
    yourInitialID = "0" + yourInitialID;
}

//uh oh whered my zero go
int realID = int.Parse(yourInitialID);
//The computer parsed 01234 as 1234



//Your process of identifying for bool
bool myNeededVar = false;

Console.WriteLine(realID);
Console.ReadKey();
```